# Как отрисовать новые данные запроса, по очереди в React/Redux Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

На данный момент у меня данные перетираются новыми. Либо выдает два одинаковых поля.

Мой slice:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { API_URL } from '../../Utils/constant';
import axios from "../../Services/apiService";

export const createShortLink = createAsyncThunk(
  'links/createShortLink',
  async (link) => {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL + `squeeze?link=${link}`)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })

    return await response
  }
);

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false,
};

const linkSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'links',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [createShortLink.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = 'loading';
    },
    [createShortLink.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      const result = Object.values(action.payload);
      console.log('result', result);
      
      const chunkArray = (arr, cnt) => (
        arr.reduce((prev, cur, i, a) => !(i % cnt) ? prev.concat([a.slice(i, i + cnt)]) : prev, [])
      );

      const newResult = (chunkArray(result, 4));
      let Array = state.items = [...newResult];  // Двумерный массив items: [[]];
      // Найти способ добавлять новые данные с запроса в массив items
      

      console.log('Array', Array);
    },
    [createShortLink.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.loading = 'rejected';
    },
  }
});

export const selectLinks = state => state.links.items;
export default linkSlice.reducer;
```

Таблица:

```
const Table = () => {

  const links = useSelector(selectLinks);
  
  return (
    <div className="container w-[80%] mt-5">
      {links?.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-slate-500">
            <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
              <tr>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
                  {item[0]}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
                  {item[3]}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
                  {item[1]}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-800 whitespace-nowrap">
                  {item[2]}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-right whitespace-nowrap">
                  <a className="text-red-500 hover:text-red-700" href="/#" >
                    Copy
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение было довольно простым:

```
const linkSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'links',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [createShortLink.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = 'loading';
    },
    [createShortLink.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      const result = Object.values(action.payload); 

      state.items = [...state.items, result]
      
      console.log('Array', Array);
    },
    [createShortLink.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.loading = 'rejected';
    },
  }
});
```